# Viability of using Cython to secure the distributed source code

Tags: python, cython, pyinstaller, decompiling

First of all, greetings. I have a source code to introduce to people to have some demos on it. However, my biggest issue is the source code security.

Depending on my findings, compiling the python files with `cython` is one of the best option to secure my source code. There are actually few problems that I need to ask.

**1)** I am pretty newbie in cython, exactly one day of researching about it, is it really the best option to secure my source code?

**2)** If cython is not the best option, I am not experienced with *C/C++*, are there any options to do so?

**3)** I have read that, practically, it is really hard to decompile the `.pyd` (I'm using Windows) files. Is it really the case?

**4)** After I got the `.pyd` file, I am planning to have a `main.py` to run it, and then using `pyinstaller` to have a standalone `.exe` file to distribute my code. Is it a viable option?

**5)** Different than above, could you suggest me further thins that I have not listed?

Thank you for your precious ideas and sparing your time to enlight me further. Any suggestions would be appriciated!